# Insert Degree Symbol in database through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, symbols

Hi StackOverflow friends,

I am storing temperature in my database but I cannot add the degree symbol. My code is:

```
$que = "Insert into tblTempForecast (DateTimePosted, Now, Tomorrow) VALUES(now(),'$CloseLow1 &deg; - $CloseHi1 &deg;','$CloseLow2 &deg; - $CloseHi2 &deg;')";
$insertTemp = mysql_query($que);
```

My `$CloseLow1` is equal to 15 and `$CloseHi1` is 20. `$CloseLow2` is 18 and `$CloseHi2` is 22.

However, with my code above, it only inserts the `$CloseLow1` and `CloseLow2`. It is supposed to insert the ff on the database:

```
ID (auto)              DateTimePosted             Now            Tomorrow
1                      2013-11-18 15:25:48       15°-20°         18°-22°
```

Comment: What do you mean by `It is supposed to insert the ff on the database:`?

Comment: I meant, it should be the one that is inserted. Instead of 15-22 and 18-22, my code only inserts 15 and 18 on the fields.

Comment: What exactly does the `$que` string look like before the query call?

Comment: I don't understand. In your question, you show `15-20` as being inserted. Is that the expected result or is that what happens now? Anyway, see STT LCU's answer below. That's the way it should be done.

Answer (score 11):

1. Don't use mysql_* functions, because they're deprecated. Learn about [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead, which is the way to do things nowadays.
2. Do not save HTML-encoded characters. Always store them as UTF-8 (or your preferred charset, even if i suggest you UTF-8 anyway)
3. If you store them as plain UTF-8 characters this issue will solve itself at once. Just remember that you need to call `htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars` on the fetched values.
4. Why are you storing your values as strings, rather than 4 separated fields? You'll be able to have much more flexibility (you can now make averages and all sorts of calculations with integers that you can't with strings) and you can leave the `&deg;` issue to your page rendering script rather than wrestle with DB character encodings.

Sorry if I don't solve directly your issue, but I think that you'll be better off in the long run if you take the high road and tackle the root of the problem rather than the superficial issue.

Expecially n° 4. Really, consider that.

Comment: Good answer. `+1` for solving the actual issue.

Comment: I'd have to strongly agree with point #4. Inserting two distinct values into a single field is a violation of the 1NF, which you simply don't do. If there is only rule you don't break in database design, that would be it.